# Angular JS chaining filterFilter

Tags: angularjs, filter

This is my angular code.

```
 $scope.names = [
      {name: 'Tobias', gender: 'm'},
      {name: 'Jeff', gender: 'm'},
      {name: 'Lisa', gender: 'f'},
      {name: 'Diana', gender: 'f'},
      {name: 'James', gender: 'm'},
      {name: 'Brad', gender: 'm'}
    ];

    $scope.filteredNames = filterFilter($scope.names, 'a');
    $scope.filteredNamesByFemale = filterFilter($scope.names, {gender: 'f'});
```

I want to know how to chain the two filters `filterFilter($scope.names, 'a')`  and `filterFilter($scope.names, {gender: 'f'})`

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$scope.filteredNames` instead of `$scope.names` in the second call.

Comment: Great idea. However, if my page has two filters types, i.e, a `select` for gender type and `text` input for names, I think there will be more and more filters apply to `$scope.filteredNames` object.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Edit your question and elaborate on what is your actual problem.